# Did the World Engine from ‘Man of Steel’ appear in Superman comic books?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Was the concept of a World Engine in "Man of Steel" derived from the Superman comics or invented just for the movie?

This article http://dccinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/World_Engine does not appear to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are no canon reference to a "World Engine" or similar gravity-based terraforming devices anywhere within the ***Superman*** canon (strongly suggesting that it was invented purely for the film), there are a number of alternate DC sources to consider;

### The [Planet Shapers](http://www.comicvine.com/planet-shaper/4055-57372/);

[image: Planet Shapers]

The Planet Shapers were used by a race called the Kherubim to terraform worlds, altering the atmosphere as well as using the DNA of local species to create subservient workers. The machine also uses a central database of pure Kherubim DNA to recreate the original Kherubim  race.

### [Thor : WorldEngine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/595960.Thor)

The only specific reference I can find to anything called a World Engine is in the comic "[Thor : Worldengine](http://www.comicvine.com/thor-worldengine/4050-39091/)" in which a device of 'unimaginable power' is used to trick [Yggdrasil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil), the World Ash into believing that Ragnarok (e.g. the end of the world) has occurred.

Given the dissimilarity between the two devices, my personal feeling is that the name is purely coincidental.

[image: Thor World Engine]

According to the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ragnar%C3%B6k);

> An eccentric physicist named Price, after ingesting hallucinagens
>   became obsessed with Ragnarok, and what humanity would be like after
>   the world ending in fire. So he created the World engine, which
>   tricked Yggdrasill into believing Ragnarok had already ocurred, and
>   began creating a new race of humans.
>
> "Nursed on nothing but the morning dew" according to Price. The
>   Post-Ragnarok Humans were gestated in sap-filled boughs that grew on
>   Yggdrasil's branches. They were designed to exist in an environment
>   filled with ash, in which they would "eat". Unfortunately, because
>   this atmosphere didn't actually exist, they all began starving to
>   death only moments after being born.

[image: World Engine 2]

Answer (score 2):

Actually The World Engine exists outside of the Superman movie, just not in the same form.  It is featured in the Marvel Universe as a large device that was used to trick Yggdrasil that Ragnarok already happened.

The concept of Superman's World Engine, as a terraforming device, was created specifically for The Man of Steel Movie though.

http://www.comicvine.com/world-engine/4055-42986/

[image]

Comment: You seem very certain that it was created specifically for the film. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Considering there is no world engine in the DC Universe the only explanation would be that they made it up for the movie...

Comment: See the above answer. Although it's called something else there are terraforming machines in the DC Universe.

Comment: Terraforming devices are usually not uncommon in any sort of medium though.

Comment: That still doesn't explain how you know that it was created *specifically* for this film, especially when it bears a reasonable similarity to the "Planet Shaper" designed by Jim Lee (whose work was heavily referenced elsewhere in the film).

Comment: I don't exactly remember was the World Engine supposed to have humans as slaves or just kill them all, because if it's the second the only similarity would be the terraforming.  I don't think the World Engine itself was used in the process of creating the Genetically-engineered Kryptonians from the codex, which differs from the Planet Shaper as well.

Comment: The World Engine in Thor bears very little similarity to the World Engine in MoS, other than its size and name obviously.

Comment: Yes it only shares the name, but the similarity in the fact that the Planet Shaper is the fact that is is a terraforming device... The only other similarity is the fact that there is a codex with genetic material of the Kryptonians but I don't believe they stated that The World Engine was going to be used in the process of using the codex to create the Kryptonian race.  The Planet shaper as stated used the central database genetic material to create the Kherubims.

Comment: Essentially if they did take ideas from the Planet Shaper, they split it into two things... The World Engine and the Codex, while the Planet Shaper itself would have used both a central database inside of it and terraforming to create the Kherubim race.

Answer (score 2):

> Was the concept of a World Engine in "Man of Steel" derived from the Superman comics or invented just for the movie?

The World Engine is the specific name they gave to the machine that Hamilton in the movie described as terraforming. It's a terraforming machine, a device to change a given planet's environment to suit a specific need. This is an old hat science fiction trope. And in fact, is something that is constantly thought of for real life. NASA and other space agencies have ideas for Terraforming Mars and the Moon, from practical methods like using bioengineered algae to (currently technologically) impossible methods like nanomachines.

While I haven't kept up with Superman or DC comics, the Justice League cartoon had a couple. The very first movie/episode "Secret Invasion" had the Imperium Ion Factories, large Atmosphere changing Smog production generators and Imperium Walkers, tri-pods with large heads. I immediately though of that when the World Engine was shown. (Walker shown, not the Factory, I can't stream the episode to take a screenshot right now).

[image]

The Dark Heart, more of a self-replicating nanomachine weapon really, is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

"The Man of Steel: Inside The Legendary World of Superman" book is part art-book and part making-of feature which gives some insight into the inspiration for the World Engine.  The idea behind it was simply driven by the plot requirements and the back history developed for Krypton and its age of exploration.  The filmmakers quite wisely saw space and exploration programs as impetus for technological innovation and proliferation... much as we use everyday technologies originally developed or inspired by our own space program.

With colonization in mind, terraforming was practically a necessity, and therefore the World Engine as a concept was developed.  However, the visual appearance of the World Engine (and Black Zero) was driven by essentially three main principles:

1. Organic Curves
2. Alien Profile
3. Age

The design principle was that most of the technology on Krypton was "grown", thus things like their armor, guns, or restraints all look biological- rather than metallic, shiny, or manufactured.  Thus the inspiration came from sources like H.R. Geiger and nature... mollusks, insects, plants, etc.

The second design principle was to create something strikingly different from traditional alien ships, and thus the incredible verticality and tri-pod like appearance of the Zero and World Engine... rather than more traditional horizontal designs.

Lastly, although not expressly stated in the film, most of the technology seen in the film is literally tech from the age of expansion, merely being used, reused, retrofitted, etc... continually passed down through the ages as society and innovation ground to a halt.  Thus the interior of the Zero is meant to be dirty and messy compared to the more uncluttered Scout Ship.

In sum, while parallel developments may have been found elsewhere, for the purposes of the film, the World Engine was an original invention for the film, driven by natural principles of plot and design, rather than something borrowed from any comic.

Comment: This answer ignored the fact that many of the film's artistic elements are clearly inspired by existing Superman/DC artists like Jim Lee. Saying that it was an *original invention* just seems unlikely.

Comment: This comment conflates the original question about the World Engine with the broad brush of "artistic elements".  Nothing about the World Engine is "clearly inspired" by any existing Superman art cited in any of the above responses.

Comment: I don't disagree that it was designed for the film.